# Calculate multiple aggregations on several variables using lapply(.SD, ...)

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to perform multiple aggregations, using `data.table`'s `lapply(.SD, ...)` approach, i.e. calculate several different summary statistics on several variables. But my guesses as to how to do this end in either errors or the equivalent of `rbind` rather than `cbind`.

For example, to get the mean and median mpg in mtcars by cyl, one could do the following:

```
mtcars.dt <- data.table(mtcars)
mtcars.dt[, list(mpg.mean = mean(mpg), mpg.median = median(mpg)), by = "cyl"]
# Result:
    cyl mpg.mean mpg.median
|1:   6    19.74       19.7
|2:   4    26.66       26.0
|3:   8    15.10       15.2
```

But applying the `.SD` approach either `rbind`s the result on the functions:

```
mtcars.dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean(x), median(x))),
          by = "cyl", .SDcols = c("mpg")]
# Result:
   cyl              mpg
1:   6 19.7428571428571
2:   6             19.7
3:   4 26.6636363636364
4:   4               26
5:   8             15.1
6:   8             15.2
```

Or breaks altogether:

```
mtcars.dt[, lapply(.SD, list(mean, median)),
          by = "cyl", .SDcols = c("mpg")]
# Result:
# Error in `[.data.table`(mtcars.dt, , lapply(.SD, list(mean, median)),  :
#  attempt to apply non-function
```

EDIT: As Senor O noted, some answers provided work for my example, but only because there's a single aggregation column. An ideal solution would work for multiple columns, for example replacing the following:

```
mtcars.dt[, list(mpg.mean = mean(mpg), mpg.median = median(mpg), 
                 hp.mean = mean(hp), hp.median = median(hp)), by = "cyl"]
# Result:
   cyl mpg.mean mpg.median hp.mean hp.median
1:   6    19.74       19.7  122.29     110.0
2:   4    26.66       26.0   82.64      91.0
3:   8    15.10       15.2  209.21     192.5
```

However, even if it works for a single column, it can still be useful. For example, my immediate use case is a function which takes a column name as a string and calculates multiple grouped-by metrics for it, something which is not possible without `.SDcols` AFAIK.

Comment: -1. This is redundant because the only case where you could expect good behavior is when `.SD` only has one column, in which case you're better of using that column name explicitly in j (`lapply(mpg, function(x) list(mean(x), median(x)))`)

Comment: Thanks for noting that solutions provided so far may address my example but not an example with multiple columns; question updated to reflect this. As I also noted in the edit though, solutions are still useful if one is providing a column to aggregated as a string, e.g. in a function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're missing a `[[1]]` or `$mpg`:

```
mtcars.dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean(x), median(x)))[[1]],
            by="cyl", .SDcols=c("mpg")]
#or
mtcars.dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean(x), median(x)))$mpg,
            by="cyl", .SDcols=c("mpg")]
#   cyl       V1   V2
#1:   6 19.74286 19.7
#2:   4 26.66364 26.0
#3:   8 15.10000 15.2
```

For the more general case, try:

```
mtcars.dt[, as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean=mean(x),
                                                        median=median(x))))),
            by="cyl", .SDcols=c("mpg", "hp")]
#    cyl mpg.mean mpg.median hp.mean hp.median
# 1:   6    19.74       19.7  122.29     110.0
# 2:   4    26.66       26.0   82.64      91.0
# 3:   8    15.10       15.2  209.21     192.5
```

(or `as.list(sapply(.SD, ...))`)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is close to possibly working for multiple columns (see question edit). Any ideas on a suitable modification?

Answer (score 6):

Realized right after clicking "ask" :) The solution is to list the `lapply`s:

```
mtcars.dt[, list(mpg.mean=lapply(.SD, mean), mpg.median=lapply(.SD, median)), 
          by="cyl", .SDcols=c("mpg")]
# Solution:
    cyl mpg.mean mpg.median
|1:   6    19.74       19.7
|2:   4    26.66       26.0
|3:   8    15.10       15.2
```