# Rename aggregated columns using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table dtTrain which has many columns. I am trying to perform 4 aggregation columns on each, [Min, Max, sd, mean].
To do this I am running the line

```
subTrain <- dtTrain[,c(min = lapply(.SD, min), 
                       max = lapply(.SD, max), 
                       sd = lapply(.SD, sd), 
                       mean = lapply(.SD, mean)), by=TrialID]
```

The problem I am having is the aggregation is working but the column headers are repeated (ie column1 is produced four times in the subTrain table).
I would prefer `[column1.min,...,column1.max...,column1.sd, ...column1.mean,...]` or in fact any column label.

Comment: `names(Result_dataframe) <- c("Min","Max","sd","Mean")`

Comment: How about using list() instead of c()?

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian you can use `setnames` instead of `names<-`

Comment: See also: [Calculate multiple aggregations with lapply(.SD, …)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151602/calculate-multiple-aggregations-with-lapply-sd); [Apply multiple functions to multiple columns in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620783/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-columns-in-data-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setnames` with `rep` to change the column names

```
res <- dtTrain[, c(lapply(.SD, min), 
        lapply(.SD, max),
        lapply(.SD, sd), 
       lapply(.SD, mean)), by=TrialID]
nm1 <- setdiff(names(dtTrain), 'TrialID')
setnames(res, 2:ncol(res), paste(nm1, rep(c('min', 'max', 'sd', 'mean'), 
                         each = length(nm1)), sep="."))
```

Comment: res1 <- setnames(res, 1:(length(res)-1), paste(nm1, rep(c('min', 'max', 'sd', 'mean'),  each = length(nm1)), sep=".")) works

Comment: Please, can either akrun or @wbm correct the final answer? Thank you.

Comment: yes, correct. I thought everything in R was zero base but a bit of a newbie. Many thanks @akrun

Answer (score 0):

Changing of column names can be done using `names()` function or `colnames()` function

```
 > names(Result_dataframe) <- c("Min","Max","sd","Mean")

 #                         OR

 > colnames(Result_dataframe) <- c("Min","Max","sd","Mean")
```